# Parameter value not accepted when trying to write to DB

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to save a date to DB, but I get a red line below the parameter `startDate` that is of format like this: 2016-05-06. It works if I hardcode the parameter like this: `StartProject = new DateTime(2016-05-06)`. Why do I get an error for this parameter?

The error message when I'm pointing on the red line: `Cannot convert from 'System.DateTime' to 'Long'`.

This is part of the code in the Action Controller

```
public ActionResult CreateProjectResource(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate) {
....
            var project = new Project
            {
              Name = projectName,
              StartProject = new DateTime(startDate),
            };

            db.Projects.Add(project);
            db.SaveChanges();
 ....
```

Comment: Its needs to be `new DateTime(2016, 05, 06)` (the constructor accepts 3 int values for year, month and day). But why are you using that? Surely you just want `StartProject = startDate`?

Comment: Put a annotation of date time with format in the StartProject property of Project class. I hope this may fix this issue

Comment: @StephenMuecke OK, is there any function within ASP.NET MVC that can convert this?

Comment: @StephenMuecke OK, the red line is gone. I thought I hade to use the new DateTime... since I have that in the Seed Method when I create some default objects. So then it's OK to save the date like: 2016-05-06 and not 2016, 05, 06?

Comment: Yes of course. There is no need to create a new `DateTime`

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thanks for your help and comments! My question is solved!

Comment: Is your StartProject property a DateTime or a long? Can you post the code for the Project class?

Answer (score 0):

As to the documentation on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime(v=vs.110).aspx),  `DateTime` does not have a constructor that takes a `DateTime` as parameter, so the compiler tries to use the only constructor with one parameter, which is `DateTime(Int64)` and expects ticks, but as a `DateTime` cannot be converted to long, there is an errormessage. EIther use it as follows:

```
var project = new Project
        {
          Name = projectName,
          StartProject = startDate
        };
```

You don't need to create a new `DateTime` object, because `DateTime` is immutable.

or if you really want to create a new DateTime as follows:

```
var project = new Project
        {
          Name = projectName,
          StartProject = new DateTime(startDate.Ticks)
        };
```